# Долго работает функция distance С++

Tags: c++, указатели

Есть код:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << "i =  " << i << endl;
    cin >> q;
    cout << "q = " << q << endl;
    st.insert(q);
    cout << "inserted" << endl;
    curr_right += distance(st.lower_bound(q), st.begin());
    cout << "end of for\n";
}
```

При вводе такого теста

```
5
5 4 2 3 1
```

Последнее что выводит программа

```
q = 3
inserted
```

А дальше ничего не выводит и не заканчивается.

То есть вставка в `set` произошла но функция `distance` как-то странно себя ведёт.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: "...В чем может быть проблема?" - основываясь на той скупой информации, которую Вы дали - ответ: в чем угодно. Возможно, что переполняется st (мы ничего не знаем об этом объекте), возможно, что не работает distance() и еще миллион причин.

Comment: Смещение итератора st.lower_bound(q) никогда не дойдет до  st.begin(), чтобы вычислить дистанцию. Тут итератор однонаправленный

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Функция distance принимает два итератора в "прямом порядке", то есть, вначале  должен быть begin.

```
distance(st.begin(), st.lower_bound(q));
```

После такого изменения оно вроде работает. Если нет - приводите больше данных, хотя бы полный пример кода, а не огрызок.

Comment: Ага. `distance` может вернуть отрицательное число для рандомаксес итераторов, а `set` такие не предоставляет.

Comment: может, потому что реализован будет через вычитание. А вот для не рандомных интераторов, оно реализуется через прямой проход и next. И если итераторы в "неправильном порядке", бежать будет долго